# Angular Bootstrap UI Typeahead not working when using async loading method

Tags: angularjs

I have this small problem with Typeahead directive here is my code so far:

```
$scope.getUserNames = function (input) {
            return $http.get(ApplicationConstants.apiUrl + 'api/Users/UserNames', {
                headers: { 'ContentType': 'application/json' },
                params: {
                    input: input
                }
            }).then(function (response) {
                $log.debug('GetUserNames:', response.data);
                return response.data;
            }, function (error) {
                $log.debug(error);
            });
        };
```

This is as required by the documentation - the promise is being returned and the contents of the response data are as follow : ['username1','username2',...]

Then in markup I have following code:

```
{{userNameSelected}}
                    <input type="text" ng-model="userNameSelected" placeholder="Type the username" typeahead="val as val for val in getUserNames($viewValue)" class="form-control">
```

I've tried using "val for val in getUserNames($viewValue)" but it also doesn't help. The problem is that the model gets updated correctly but no dropdown under the typeahead input is being shown - no results. Am I doing something wrong ? Just to mention I have latest angular and angular-ui-bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the input or type something in, does your input have an empty dropdown or not even that? Did you check if you request response is coming through? Since you've tried using `val for val in getUserNames` I would guess your problem is you `response`.

Also, try removing your `headers: { 'ContentType': 'application/json' },`, sometimes you may forget to configure your service's allowed requests and so. You should be gettin something like

> Request header field ContentType is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

in your console

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have proper CORS setup but tried removing the header , didn't help. I get the response correctly since I put debug statement before getting response and I get array of strings. I entered to the input the values matching the ones returned in the response (expected ones). This is strange, maybe there is a bug with new versions ... What is interesting is that the example of using static array as the source works correctly.

Comment: I replicated your code in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dRjAXtKXOvzOHmDHb17y?p=preview) and it works like charm, of course, considering your array is coming as good as the example's.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I see that it is working correctly there. I probably have confilict with other libraries I use in my project

Comment: Thanks again for the effort. I found the reason why it wasn't working. I'm using in my setup angular-block-ui library and it causes conflict - when I enable it on my module's list in the main app object then the dropdown of typeahead isn't shown. I'll need to find the fix there.